# Basic and Advanced Compression (Compression Differences)

Tags: oracle, compression

I wanted to test the possible compression rate for a specific set of data inside Oracle database comparing the two features, namely Basic Compression and Advanced Row Compression.

So I've created two compressed tables (one using basic compression and the other using advanced row compression). Both methods try to remove duplicates by saving the value in a symbol table inside the block header. It seems that both work the same way somehow. I get different compression ratios for the compressed tables. The table compressed with basic compression consumes less space than the one with advanced compression. How is that? Can somebody explain it to me? There must be some differences in the algorithms. I couldn't find the reason for such results.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/dbstorage/post/when-to-use-the-various-types-of-oracle-data-compression

Comment: @Martheen If they use the same algorithm, then how do I get different results? The difference is like 110 MBs between both compressed tables (700 MB for basic compression and 810 MB for advanced compressed, while uncompressed table is taking up to 1,1 GB); both inserted through direct path inserts).

Comment: Even with the same algorithm, treating the block as just a bulk of data instead of adjusting the row to speed up the row operation will give you a different compression ratio. Basically, row compression sacrifices some storage for better modification performance.

Comment: @Martheen They were inserted the same way to both compressed tables. I've tried this multiple times. If they work the same way, then how could I get different results? Sorry for not getting it right away, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @alexzhvv, I think the claim that the algorithm is the same is probably overstated. There's the obvious difference in when the compression happens and the # of rows it has at that time to work with. Add that to the likely difference in column duplicate frequency in a direct path array insert vs. various sessions doing single row inserts, the difference in `PCTFREE` to reduce chaining, and you're not going to expect the same results from each. (Also be aware that to test advanced compression properly you should not be doing direct path inserts. It was designed for conventional `INSERT VALUES`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BASIC** compression compresses blocks on direct path load (`INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO x SELECT ...` or `CREATE TABLE x AS SELECT...` or SQL Loader with `DIRECT=TRUE`, etc.) using an old algorithm, and does not cost anything extra. Updates on basic compressed rows cause immediate decompression and row chaining so you really don't want to use this if your segment gets any updates. As it does not compress on conventional/buffered inserts, the only use for it if you're not direct path loading is to reorganize (move) a table or partition that is already loaded to compress it afterwards, usually to save space, though it *can* also help performance of full table scans on non-Exadata systems with slow I/O throughput by reducing the I/O needed to read the segment (at the cost of additional CPU for decompression at the database layer).

Advanced or **OLTP** compression aims at providing compression to incoming data where the inserts are conventional/buffered and scattered (e.g. `INSERT INTO x VALUES...`). It does so by postponing the compression until it has enough data in a block to make it worth compressing. It can compress rows in a block that were inserted individually by different sessions at different times, making it a different algorithm, even if there are some similarities. It also retains the default `PCTFREE 10` rather than overriding it to `PCTFREE 0` like BASIC compression does, which also results in a different compression ratio. Its compression ratios are usually slightly inferior or at best comparable to that of BASIC. Updating more than a few OLTP compressed rows in a block will quickly use up the PCTFREE space and also cause chaining, so you don't want this on a table that gets lots of updates. Lastly, and most problematically, **this is an extra-cost option and requires the very expensive Advanced Compression Option (ACO)**. Oracle's auditing will be a nasty surprise if they find this and you haven't paid for it. Overall it's my opinion that its benefits (which are meager) are overweighed by its negatives, and at such a high cost it's not worth it (IMO).

Here's a whitepaper that discusses it in detail, though of course it's marketing lit and so a bit overly positive about it:

[Advanced Compression Whitepaper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/advanced-compression-whitepaper-130502.pdf)

In Exadata, there is a set of for Hybrid Columnar Compression (**HCC**) types (*Query Low, Query High, Archive Low, Archive High*) which compress column-major data within compression units (CUs) to get fantastic compression ratios, much better than BASIC. Plus, updates don't chain right away - initial updates will migrate rows to OLTP in new blocks, and it's only on second update of the same row that chaining will happen. Still, it's best to hold off on HCC compression for tables that get heavy updates. It used to be that HCC compression would only happen on direct path load (like BASIC) but in 12.2 they enhanced it so any array insert (`INSERT SELECT`) can be compressed even if the append hint isn't used. In the world of Exadata, HCC is far more desirable than BASIC or OLTP.

In summary, then, all of Oracle's compression algorithms are different, intended for different purposes, and can be expected to yield different compression ratios. Testing your data (a sufficient amount of it, like a million rows at least) is the only way to know for sure how each option will perform. If you want to dig deeper and get into the weeds, you can always do block dumps of differently compressed blocks with the same data and compare how the data is stored in each.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about something similar to your answer. Well, now it all makes sense to me :D Lessons learned.

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate the compression ratio with `DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO` procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_blkcnt_cmp    PLS_INTEGER;
  l_blkcnt_uncmp  PLS_INTEGER;
  l_row_cmp       PLS_INTEGER;
  l_row_uncmp     PLS_INTEGER;
  l_cmp_ratio     NUMBER;
  l_comptype_str  VARCHAR2(32767);
  l_index_cr      DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMPRECLIST;

    TYPE comptypesType IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
    comptypesTable comptypesType := comptypesType(
        --DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_BASIC,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_ADVANCED,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_QUERY_HIGH,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_QUERY_LOW,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_ARCHIVE_HIGH,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_ARCHIVE_LOW);
        
    comptypesIndex comptypesType := comptypesType(
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_INDEX_ADVANCED_HIGH,
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_INDEX_ADVANCED_LOW);
  
BEGIN

    FOR i IN comptypesTable.FIRST..comptypesTable.LAST LOOP
        DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO(
            scratchtbsname  => 'RADIUS_DATA',
            ownname         => USER,
            objname         => 'RADACCT_MOBILE_COMPRESS',
            subobjname      => NULL, 
            comptype        => comptypesTable(i),
            blkcnt_cmp      => l_blkcnt_cmp,
            blkcnt_uncmp    => l_blkcnt_uncmp,
            row_cmp         => l_row_cmp,
            row_uncmp       => l_row_uncmp,
            cmp_ratio       => l_cmp_ratio,
            comptype_str    => l_comptype_str,
            subset_numrows  => DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_RATIO_MINROWS,
            objtype         => DBMS_COMPRESSION.OBJTYPE_TABLE);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of blocks used (compressed)       : ' ||  l_blkcnt_cmp);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : ' ||  l_blkcnt_uncmp);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : ' ||  l_row_cmp);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : ' ||  l_row_uncmp);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Compression ratio                        : ' ||  l_cmp_ratio);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Compression type                         : ' ||  l_comptype_str);
    END LOOP;
        
END;
```

As far as I remember `DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_BASIC` is not supported by `DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO`. You may manually compress a table/partition and compare the sizes.

And here an example result:

```
----

Number of blocks used (compressed)       : 640
Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : 1408
Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : 203
Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : 92
Compression ratio                        : 2.2
Compression type                         : "Compress Advanced"

----

Number of blocks used (compressed)       : 1583
Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : 10837
Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : 632
Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : 92
Compression ratio                        : 6.8
Compression type                         : "Compress Query High"

----

Number of blocks used (compressed)       : 2611
Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : 10837
Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : 383
Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : 92
Compression ratio                        : 4.1
Compression type                         : "Compress Query Low"

----

Number of blocks used (compressed)       : 1560
Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : 10837
Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : 641
Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : 92
Compression ratio                        : 6.9
Compression type                         : "Compress Archive High"

----

Number of blocks used (compressed)       : 1501
Number of blocks used (uncompressed)     : 10837
Number of rows in a block (compressed)   : 666
Number of rows in a block (uncompressed) : 92
Compression ratio                        : 7.2
Compression type                         : "Compress Archive Low"

----
```

The compression ratio you get, depends on the data structure in the table. Do you have many different values in rows or columns and it also depends on the data types.